# C# How to create methods that can by called from .xaml files like "OnLoad"

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface

In c#, when creating a .xaml object such as a page, one will often use code like

```
Loaded="OnLoad".
```

This will cause your "OnLoad" method to be called inside the corresponding .cs file. Which would look like

```
private void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){ }.
```

I am trying to create a custom reusable .xaml object which has it's own method say "OnButtonPressed" exactly like the one above. How would I go about doing this.

Could someone provide a simple example, or at least point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Matthew

Comment: You need only create an event on your class

Comment: You can do it exactly like you have in the OP.  Just create an event in your code behind and bind to it by name in your `xaml`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am new to xaml, and I still don't know how to do this. I keep reading and learning more, but I am not there yet. I would appreciate an idiot proof complete example, or even a link to an article showing how to do this. What you have told me isn't quite clear to me, as I currently have a very minimal grasp of the language.